# UITextFields aren't allowing me to edit text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've programmatically created two `UITextField`s in my iOS app, and set their text to the `_minPrice` and `_minPrice` variables, respectively.

The `_minPrice` and `_maxPrice` values appear correctly in the two fields, but tapping on them doesn't allow the user to edit them, they just remain those static values, backspacing doesn't work. Is there anything about my code thats preventing the text fields from being edited?

```
    // Min Price
    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-25, -76, 70, 30)];
    tf.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:14];
    tf.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tf.text= _minPrice;

    tf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    tf.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
    tf.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    tf.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
    tf.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

    // Max Price
    UITextField *tf1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, -76, 70, 30)];
    tf1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tf1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:14];
    tf1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tf1.text= _maxPrice;

    tf1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    tf1.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
    tf1.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    tf1.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
    tf1.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 400, 400)];
    [view addSubview:tf];
    [view addSubview:tf1];

    [self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: Maybe they've seen how you type. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is clearly the frames you're setting...

Setting the color of the view you add the labels to to blue reveals your problem:

[image]

If you ensure that the labels are actually within the view you add them to (i.e. not negative), editing will be fine. All I did was change the negative x and y values in `tf` to positive, and they were editable:

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 76, 70, 30)];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this! Maybe there is another view at the top of the textField

```
your_textfield.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

If this doesn't work

add another line

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: your_textfield];
```

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions, and I still can't seem to be able to edit the fields. I think there is in fact a view on top of it, but how can I be able to tell?

Comment: @Ghobs - I once wrote a little routine to find the view on top of a button.  It's fairly easy -- just a recursive search to find overlapping views, then examine the Z order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add delegate methods on your textfields. Like

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
 //  ADD BREAKPOINT HERE.
}
```

Check if it goes to that line of code. If not maybe there's a view on top of it. Or you can try to bring textfield to front like .

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourTextfield];`

But this isn't a good example of how you fix the problem. Just to test if there is a view on top of it.